# How to add items to a spinner in Android?

Tags: android, spinner

How to add items to a spinner?

Comment: If you want to add dynamically add items to your list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 168):

XML file:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java file:

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] arraySpinner = new String[] {
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
        };
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

[See spinner example](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-spinner-example).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: use this android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item in place of this android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item it looks lot better

Comment: What is array_spinner? name of the array is arraySpinner. is it spelling mistake or it has to be like that only>

Comment: `this` have to be replace by a `Context` object if you want to use this outside of an `Activity` object.

Comment: Consider adding `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);` (before `s.setAdapter(adapter);` to make the dropdown look better.

Comment: @StephenM changed the link

Answer (score 130):

I've found another option: spinner definition in the layout file

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/spin"
    android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"
/>
```

Items definition in the file array.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="spinnerItems">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
        <item>item4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

[Link to the full source of the code](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

Comment: I tried all the methods above and a few other tutorials, but this i the only one that worked for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: This should be top answer. Clean.

Answer (score 33):

Try this code:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
list.add("Item 4");
list.add("Item 5");

final String[] str = {"Report 1", "Report 2", "Report 3", "Report 4", "Report 5"};

final Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp1.setAdapter(adp1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp2.setAdapter(adp2);

sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

You can also add spinner item value through String array xml file..

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Spinner_ex5</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string-array name="str2">
        <item>Data 1</item>
        <item>Data 2</item>
        <item>Data 3</item>
        <item>Data 4</item>
        <item>Data 5</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In mainActivity.java:

```
final Spinner sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adp3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                                    R.array.str2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

adp3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp3.setAdapter(adp3);
sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ss = sp3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Array Item One</item>
<item>Array Item Two</item>
<item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

In your layout:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/array_name"
    />
```

Comment: but then how do you get the selected item?

Comment: First TypeCast in Java file. Then use                                         
                                                                                                   
 Spinner spinner; 
 spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        
        
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
            }
        });

Answer (score 9):

For adding item in Spinner, you can do one thing, try to create an adapter and then add/remove items into the adapter, then you can easily bind that adapter to spinner by using **`setAdapter()`** method.

Here is an example:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.add(item1);
adapter.add(item2);
adapter.add(item3);
adapter.add(item4);
adapter.add(item5);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply i got the solution also now i am facing one problem on it.

Comment: I want to fetch the selected item of spinner i.e its position as further i want to pass it to other method see what i did...   dataspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new myitemlistener());

Comment: dataspin is my Spinner object

Comment: @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) 
  {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String p=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   int pos=(int) parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
   System.out.println("position of spinner..."+pos);
   setSearchView(pos);
  }

Comment: if i do this than spinner item is not displaying

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged(); Before you set the adapter?Are you serious?

Answer (score 6):

This code basically reads a JSON array object and convert each row into an option in the spinner that is passed as a parameter:

```
public ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapterFromArrayListForSpinner(ArrayList<JSONObject> aArrayList, String aField)
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> aArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    aArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item); //android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < aArrayList.size(); i++)
        {
            aArrayAdapter.add(aArrayList.get(i).getString(aField)); 
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ShowMessage("Error while reading the JSON list");
    }
    return aArrayAdapter;       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a spinner to the XML layout, and then add this code to the Java file:

```
Spinner spinner;
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1) ;
java.util.ArrayList<String> strings = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
strings.add("Mobile") ;
strings.add("Home");
strings.add("Work");
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(AddMember.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, strings);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: 'SpinnerAdapter' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 1):

**Add this code after updating the list**

*Suppose:*

The ArrayAdapter<String> variable name is **dataAdapter**,
and the List variable name is **keys**.

- dataAdapter.addAll(keys);
- dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to use the material spinner library: https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner

first add to your project:

```
compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.4'
```

and use like this:

```
<com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and java code that you can add items in java so easy:

```
MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setItems("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5");
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {

  @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
    Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked " + item, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add **one more item** to *Spinner* you can:

```
ArrayAdapter myAdapter = 
  ((ArrayAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter());

myAdapter.add(myValue);

myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: "UnsupportedOperationException" occured

Answer (score 0):

It's just to clear the adapter, add all itens and notify change like below:

```
  public void show(List<Object> objLIst) {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(objLIst);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```