# Spinner added value in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to add local pin codes in spinner.

For example : 600000 to 600113

How to add these in spinner?

Comment: have a try with this http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517.. before posting a question over here please search in google about your requirement.

Comment: Just use a loop to generate a string array with the numbers, and add it to the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an adapter and then add items to the adapter.

You are beginner, I post full code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Spinner addnum_spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addnum_spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String[] myarray=new String[113];// create an array
    long a=600000;
    String v;
    for(int i=0;i<=113;i++)
    {
    v=String.valueOf(a);
    myarray[i]=v;
    a=a+1;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,myarray);
    addnum_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: a++ error occure.I think show it convert string.

Comment: long and int how to add two datatype in one value? then how to convert to string a++?

Comment: at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)

Comment: Hi when i click spinner this type of error Occure

Comment: I asked already to post your code. Edit your question and post the code

Comment: i have used your code dear but when i was click spinner nullpointexpection through it.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<113;i++)
  {
  int a=600000;
  String v;
  v=String.valueOf(a);
  // or v=Integer.toString(a);
  myarray[i]=v;
  i=i+1;
  a=a+1;
  }

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,myarray);
      addnum_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickedListener);

Comment: String myarray=new String[113];

Comment: i can't touch spinner .

Comment: I've edited. now it will work. sure. I checked. all the best

Comment: hi i have clear that issue yesterday night Please see that

Comment: for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
  {
  myarray[i]=String.valueOf(a);
  a++;
  }

Comment: @Gomathi Have you got it, is it working?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of questions already on SO addressing this type of issues. Please have a look at them.

You can check this previous SO question : **[How can I add items to a spinner in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android)**

Comment: ArrayAdapter.createFromResource we can't sent it argument in String

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you mean you can't pass String to ArrayAdapter.createFromResource ?        `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.str2, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);` Here str2 is string array.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of values which you want to populate in the spinner like this:

```
      String []Pin = {"600000","600113"};
```

Inatialize, then bind it to the spinner like this:

```
      Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.YourSpinner); //From XML
      ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Pin);
      spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1); // The drop down vieww
      YourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
      YourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simpler:

```
long int start=600000;
String myarray[]=new String[113];
for(int i=0;i<=113;i++)
{
myarray[i++]=a+"";
a++;
}
```

and then

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
myarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Change type myarray to int error show it.What to do?

Comment: but only one issues in arrayadapter myarray error show it.In that error myarray convert to integer.

Comment: No it is not work.Change type myarray to int error show it?

Comment: Your code only i have added .just error show it createFromResource we can't added String.but we are using myarray in string format.

Comment: just check it ArrayAdapter.createFromResource

Comment: again error show it. The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String[], int)

Comment: Please see second line,ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
myarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

Comment: No this is your ans right? Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
myarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Please see second line

Comment: Can you sent it your code again