# How to display qr scanner scanned result inside textbox

Tags: java, android

Integrated qr scanner in my android app..it working fine..its displaying scanned result in the form toast in my android app..but instead of that I want to display scanned result inside text box...can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

it's simple. instead of the Toast, you need to put the following code.

```
TextViewName.setText(ResultText);
```

Comment: Hi how about display in spinner ?

Comment: add each result to arraylist .then load it into spinner

Comment: Hello Sathish thanks for your replay. do you have any sample code for the same?

Comment: i don't have sample code. just try with `ArrayList`

Comment: @Leace if you wan to add data into spinner try to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android

Comment: Skullper thank you for your feedback. I would like to show the barcode scanner result in to spinner box. In-fact barcode scanner result is showing successfully in textview now but samething i want to display in spinner

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which is working fine for Display the barcoder reader result in textview but i am unable to display the barcode reader result in spinner...

```js
public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static final String BARCODE_KEY = "BARCODE";
  Spinner s1, s2, s3, s4;
  private Barcode barcodeResult;
  private Barcode spinner3;
  private Button button3;
  TextView tex, tex1, result1;
  DatabaseHandler dbhndlr;
  Cursor spinner1csr, spinner2csr, spinner3csr, spinner4csr, search;
  SimpleCursorAdapter sca, sca2, sca3, sca4, sca6;
  long spinner1_selected = 0;
  CheckBox ck1, ck2, ck3, ck4, ck5, ck6, ck7, ck8;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

      result1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barcodeResult);

      assertNotNull(result1);

      s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
      s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
      s3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

      dbhndlr = new DatabaseHandler(this);

      final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
      button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          startScan();
        }
      });
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Barcode restoredBarcode = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BARCODE_KEY);
        if (restoredBarcode != null) {
          result1.setText(restoredBarcode.rawValue);
          barcodeResult = restoredBarcode;
        }
      }
      private void startScan() {
        final MaterialBarcodeScanner materialBarcodeScanner = new MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder()
          .withActivity(SpinnerEx4Activity.this)
          .withEnableAutoFocus(true)
          .withBleepEnabled(true)
          .withBackfacingCamera()
          .withCenterTracker()
          .withText("Scanning...")
          .withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
              spinner3 = barcode;
              result1.setText(barcode.rawValue);
            }
          })
          .build();
        materialBarcodeScanner.startScan();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BARCODE_KEY, barcodeResult);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      }
```