# Qr scanner scanned result in fragment

Tags: java, android, buttonclick

I am beginner to android..I integrated qr scanner ZXING library in my app..in fragment layout..this library working..On click button..qr scanner is opening..but scanned result is not displaying inside edit text  in fragment layout..how to display result in fragment?

below is my On click button code

```
   @Override

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.configure_switch,container,false);

    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
             integrator.initiateScan();

             }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you receive the result to a activity get the current fragment and call that method like below 
`CustomFragmentClass` will be your fragment.

```
 Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment instanceof CustomFragmentClass){
     fragment.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
    }
```

or you can also refer this [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: problem is if i use above code i am able to display result in One fragment .if i want to dispaly result in one more fragment how to do that

Comment: then send broadcast in both the fragments so u can achieve the result!

Answer (score 1):

it's simple. after getting scanned result, you need to put the following code.

```
YourEditTextName.setText(ResultText);
```

look as my related answer here,

[ https://stackoverflow.com/a/36788367/3981656 ]

here is the full code,

> MainActivity.java

```
package futurevision.jsk.barcodesanner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

private Button scanBtn;
private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
    }
    else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

}

> IntentIntegrator.java

```
package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class IntentIntegrator {

public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16 bits
private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
        "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
private static final String BSPLUS_PACKAGE = "com.srowen.bs.android";

// supported barcode formats
public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =
        list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
                "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections.singleton("QR_CODE");
public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections.singleton("DATA_MATRIX");

public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

public static final List<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections.singletonList(BS_PACKAGE);
public static final List<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(
        BS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner
        BSPLUS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner+
        BSPLUS_PACKAGE + ".simple" // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
        // What else supports this intent?
);

private final Activity activity;
private String title;
private String message;
private String buttonYes;
private String buttonNo;
private List<String> targetApplications;
private final Map<String,Object> moreExtras;

public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
    message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
    buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
    buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
    targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
    moreExtras = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
    title = activity.getString(titleID);
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
    message = activity.getString(messageID);
}

public String getButtonYes() {
    return buttonYes;
}

public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
    this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
}

public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
    buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
}

public String getButtonNo() {
    return buttonNo;
}

public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
    this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
}

public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
    buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
}

public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
    return targetApplications;
}

public final void setTargetApplications(List<String> targetApplications) {
    if (targetApplications.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No target applications");
    }
    this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
}

public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
    this.targetApplications = Collections.singletonList(targetApplication);
}

public Map<String,?> getMoreExtras() {
    return moreExtras;
}

public final void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
    moreExtras.put(key, value);
}


public final AlertDialog initiateScan() {
    return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
}

public final AlertDialog initiateScan(Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
    Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
    intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    // check which types of codes to scan for
    if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
        // set the desired barcode types
        StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
        for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
            if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
                joinedByComma.append(',');
            }
            joinedByComma.append(format);
        }
        intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
    }


    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
    startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
    return null;
}


protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
}

private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (availableApps != null) {
        for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
            String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
                return packageName;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
    downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
    downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String packageName = targetApplications.get(0);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                // Hmm, market is not installed
                Log.w(TAG, "Google Play is not installed; cannot install " + packageName);
            }
        }
    });
    downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
    });
    return downloadDialog.show();
}

public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
            int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null : intentOrientation;
            String errorCorrectionLevel = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
            return new IntentResult(contents,
                    formatName,
                    rawBytes,
                    orientation,
                    errorCorrectionLevel);
        }
        return new IntentResult();
    }
    return null;
}

public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text, CharSequence type) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
    String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
    if (targetAppPackage == null) {
        return showDownloadDialog();
    }
    intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    attachMoreExtras(intent);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    return null;
}

private static List<String> list(String... values) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values));
}

private void attachMoreExtras(Intent intent) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : moreExtras.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        // Kind of hacky
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Long) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Float) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Bundle) value);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra(key, value.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

> IntentResult.java

```
package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

public final class IntentResult {

private final String contents;
private final String formatName;
private final byte[] rawBytes;
private final Integer orientation;
private final String errorCorrectionLevel;

IntentResult() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null);
}

IntentResult(String contents,
             String formatName,
             byte[] rawBytes,
             Integer orientation,
             String errorCorrectionLevel) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
    this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
}


public String getContents() {
    return contents;
}


public String getFormatName() {
    return formatName;
}


public byte[] getRawBytes() {
    return rawBytes;
}


public Integer getOrientation() {
    return orientation;
}


public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
    return errorCorrectionLevel;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
    dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
    int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
    dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
    dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
    return dialogText.toString();
}

}
```

Happy coding.!!!

Comment: I am not getting scanned result only..can you help me

Comment: This code working..result displaying in activity ..but if I want to display result in fragment layout..this code is not working..OnActivityResult method not working in fragment..any solution for this