# How to add Strings to a spinner without .xml and Resources

Tags: android, spinner

It's quite simple. I just want to add `Strings` to a `Spinner` without using the .`xml` and without using the `Resources` folder.

I used `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, but I didn't find any solution to my problem.

I have seen *[How can I add items to a spinner in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android)*, but it doesn't work in my case...

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar3, menu);
    setTitle("");

    String[] arraySpinner = new String[] {
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    };
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.array.spinner_values);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    return true;
}
```

Note: This code doesn't run since I need a type of layout, but I don't know what layout...

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't know what your question is exactly.

Comment: @SushobhNadiger adding items to a Spinner without using the .xml and without using the R.array

Comment: I have added an answer , please check if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add items to a spinner in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android)

Comment: @JohnJoe yep, but it doesn't work in my case...

Comment: You should add the code inside `onCreate` method

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "doesn't work in my case" means. FWIW, here is a complete sample app showing defining a `Spinner` from a Java array: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Selection/Spinner

Comment: All the snippets shared here are correct and working samples. I use Spinner all the time as many developers here. If it crashes share logcat, check why and in which line it crashes.

Comment: Any updates ???

Comment: nope... doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change to this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);`

> It crashes: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method Line: s.setAdapter(adapter);

2. Initialize them inside `onCreate` method, not inside `onCreateOptionsMenu`

   ```
    public class SpinnerExample extends Activity {    

         private String[] arraySpinner;

           @Override
           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.main);

               this.arraySpinner = new String[] {
                   "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
               };
               Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
               ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
               s.setAdapter(adapter);
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter aa = new
    ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
```

Comment: It crashes: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 

Line: s.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @HessianMad: Presumably, `s` is `null`. That is not a problem with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String categoryItem1 = "item1";
String categoryItem2 = "item2";
String categoryItem3 = "item3";
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
categories.add(categoryItem1);
categories.add(categoryItem2);
categories.add(categoryItem3);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinnner_item, categories);
// attaching data adapter to spinner
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Crashes in the same line as ArrayAdapter aa = new 
  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arraySpinner );

Comment: Are you sure that you are instantiating the Spinner, or inflating it from the correct layout of your activity/fragment?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a Kotlin approach:

```
private fun setUpTranslateToSpinner() {
    val languages = listOf(
        "English",
        "German",
        "Russian",
        "Arabic",
        "Japanese",
        "Chinese"
    ).sorted()

    ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages).apply {
        setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        translateToSpinner.adapter = this
    }

    translateToSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)
            item.let { Log.e(TAG, item.toString()) }
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }
    }
}
```