# Add item to resource file

Tags: java, android, spinner

How to programmatically add item to strings.xml for spinner's string-array?

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/tags"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/tags" />
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="tags">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
    <item>item4</item>
</string-array>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add items to a spinner in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add data to application resources programmatically. Resources are part of compiled, packed and signed APK package and therefore can't be modified.
What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add things to resources programmatically.  But a Spinner doesn't need to go off a resource file.  Use an in memory list of items, and modify that.

Answer (score 0):

If try to add data in spinner programmtically.

there is only one way use database like #firebase which update realtime data.

"without database it not possible."