# How to populate an Android Spinner from a Json file URL

Tags: android, json

I have the following Json Format file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "game_genre": "RPG"
     },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "game_genre": "Action"
     }
]
```

on a remote location:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/genre/?format=json (Ddjango Format)
and i want to populate an Android spinner with the respective id so that can perform a search later depending on the id of the genre. I read the other threads but since i am new into android i don't know where to start.
i have the Json parser file included in my project

Comment: Does this have anything to do with django?

Comment: That's the django rest framework default JSON output

Comment: but it doesn't matter what framework is being used, your question is just about how to process it in an android app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for JSON parsing :

```
String json = "[ { id: 1, game_genre: RPG }, { id: 2, game_genre : Action }]";


    if (json != null) {
        try {
                ArrayList<String> game = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList<Integer> id = new ArrayList();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    game.add(jsonObject1.getString("game_genre"));
                    id.add(Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.getString("id")));
                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Cannot get json from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Then you just need to pass the game ArrayList to the Spinner adapter.
[How can I add items to a spinner in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241660/how-can-i-add-items-to-a-spinner-in-android)